# Error while trying to upload csv files to BigQuery

Tags: sql, csv, time, google-bigquery, format

Trying to upload the CSV file. Selected auto-detect Schema. Then error as below:

*Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '5/2/2016 11:59:59 PM' as TIMESTAMP for field Date (position 1) starting at location 60 with message 'Invalid time zone: PM'*

Appreciate the help in solving it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your date with something like this:

```
var date_for_BQ = new Date(your_date.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.